# How to prove $\int_{\Omega} \mathbf{y} \ dV = \mathbf{0}$ for a symmetric domain $\Omega$

Tags: integration, symmetry

How can I show that this equation holds for a symmetric domain $\Omega$
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} \mathbf{y} \ dV = 0
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{y}$ is an arbitrary vector within the domain.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *symmetric*.

Comment: I don't know the correct terminology but what I mean by symmetry is something like the symmetry of a rectangle or a circle

Comment: But you have to specify the symmetry. If a domain in $\Bbb R^2$ is merely symmetric about the $x_1$-axis, then your statement is false. You need it to be symmetric about the origin: If $\mathbf y\in\Omega$, then $-\mathbf y\in\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I was actually thinking about the symmetry with respect to the origin. Could you please describe that in detail when that's the case?

Comment: I don't know your background or how sophisticated an approach you take to multiple integrals. I would suggest thinking about approximating the integral by a finite sum, dividing $\Omega$ symmetrically into lots of little cubes and choosing $\mathbf y_i$ and $-\mathbf y_i$ as the centers of the respective cubes.

Comment: I will definitely try your suggestion thank you. But I also would love to see how you would approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that $Ω=Ω_1\cup (-Ω_1)$, where $-Ω_1:=\{-x| x\in Ω_1\}$. Then we get $\int_Ω ydV=\int_{Ω_1} ydV+\int_{-Ω_1}ydV=\int_{Ω_1} ydV+\int_{Ω_1}-y(1)dV=0$, where we changed the variables from $y$ to $-y$ via transformation $T(y)=-y$ with absolute value of Jacobian $|J(T)|=1$.